# Prove that $\int_0^\infty y^{\frac12} e^{-y^2} \int_0^\infty y^{-\frac12} e^{-y^2} =\frac{\pi}{2^{\frac32}}$

Tags: improper-integrals, gamma-function

My attempt:

$\int_0^\infty y^{\frac12} e^{-y^2}$

$=\frac12 e^{-z} z^ {-\frac14} dz$, using the transformation: $y^2=z$, i.e. $y=z^\frac12$

$=\frac12 e^{-z} z^ {1-\frac54} dz$

$=\Gamma\frac54$

$=\frac14\Gamma\frac14$

Similarly, $\int_0^\infty y^{-\frac12} e^{-y^2}= \Gamma \frac34$

I can't take it beyond this. Can someone please help? I know I'm supposed to get a $\Gamma \frac12$ but I didn't. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Just for completeness, the mistake was that you want the 3rd line of your calculation to look like $\frac12 e^{-z} z^{\frac34-1}$ and not $\frac12 e^{-z} z^{1-\frac54}$. So the values were $\Gamma\frac34$ and $\Gamma\frac14$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in determining $\Gamma$ values. Let's use the [Pi function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Pi_function), $\Pi(x)=\int_0^\infty t^x e^{-t}\,dt=\Gamma(x+1)$, which makes things clearer.

The first integral is $1/2\,\Pi(-1/4)$ and the second is $1/2\,\Pi(-3/4)$. We know $\Pi(1/4)=1/4\,\Pi(-3/4)$, so using the reflection formula
$$1/4\,\Pi(-1/4)\,\Pi(-3/4)=\Pi(-1/4)\,\Pi(1/4)=\frac{\pi/4}{\sin(\pi/4)}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Pi function is out of my syllabus, I'm afraid. I can do this only using Gamma or Beta functions for my exams. Thanks for teaching me though! :)

Comment: @Diya $\Pi(x) = \Gamma(x+1)$, it's just a shifted Gamma, I'll mention it explicitly in the answer and if you don't like it, just replace it everywhere by Gamma :) I just like it because it makes formulas clearer and it matches the factorial exactly.

Comment: No, I like it, it makes calculations so much easier! I'm just not allowed to use it at school, that's all.

Comment: @Diya I understand. Then just replace $\Pi(-1/4), \Pi(-3/4), \Pi(1/4)$ by $\Gamma(3/4), \Gamma(1/4), \Gamma(5/4)$ and use the reflection formula in the form $\Gamma(1-z)\,\Gamma(1+z)=\frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)}$ which easily follows from the one on the Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you so much, again :)